# After fresh install of Raspberry OS the menu bar is missing in tightvnc session, how to fix?

Tags: vnc, lxde, taskbar

The menu bar is only missing in the TightVNC client display :1 whereas it is present in the session connected to a HDMI monitor.

On the HDMI monitor session I can open an `lxterminal` (about says 0.3.2) from the menu bar (LXDE).

Whereas right clicking on a folder and "Open in Terminal" gives me an Xfce terminal (about says 0.8.7.4).

In `raspi-config` the default display resolution was not changed. The black border around the screen on the HDMI monitor was removed. (I have the same settings on an rp3b+ with an older install and have no problems with the menu bar, also using TightVNC).

I was not able getting the menu to show up.

The fresh install was done with "Raspberry Pi Imager" and chosen "Raspberry Pi OS (32 bit) published 2021-03-04". (I tried it twice with the same result).

```
  Operating System: Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
            Kernel: Linux 5.10.17-v7l+
```

Changing the geometry (resolution) of the VNC server process doesn't help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As it turns out, **pulseaudio** was causing this error.
I looked at /home/pi/.cache/lxsession/LXDE-pi/run.log and compared it to the same log on my other raspberry 3b+ that doesn't have the problem. The following lines stood out:

```
** (lxpanel:1262): WARNING **: 10:29:58.402: init context: err:6 Connection refused

Assertion 'pthread_mutex_lock(&m->mutex) == 0' failed at pulsecore/mutex-posix.c:90, 
function pa_mutex_lock(). Aborting.
** Message: 10:29:58.411: app.vala:130: lxpanel exit with this type of exit: 6
** Message: 10:29:58.411: app.vala:148: Exit not normal, try to reload
```

I found a solution here https://retropie.org.uk/forum/topic/28910/making-sound-back-after-december-update-broke-pixel-desktop/3

```
sudo apt remove lxplug-volumepulse
```

It worked better than the following solution:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/445386/pulseaudio-server-connection-failure-connection-refused-debian-stretch using this answer:

```
# clean and reinstall pulseaudio
sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio
sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio
sudo apt-get -f install && sudo apt-get -y autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get clean && sudo sync && echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
# fixes user folder permissions
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER $HOME/
# then reboot
sudo reboot
```

Answer (score 1):

I would start by running `ps axf` while the system runs with HDMI screen attached, and compare the ouput to whatever you get when running the VNC. Either `lxpanel` is not started in the second case, or it is started with a different command line, and you need to figure out where the differences start to decide which config files to check first.

For reference, this is the process tree I have on Pi OS with a local session:

```
  531 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/sbin/lightdm
  603 tty7     Ssl+ 575:20  \_ /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch
 1123 ?        Sl     0:00  \_ lightdm --session-child 14 17
 1146 ?        Ssl    0:29      \_ /usr/bin/lxsession -s LXDE-pi -e LXDE
 1205 ?        Ss     0:04          \_ /usr/bin/ssh-agent x-session-manager
 1251 ?        S      0:22          \_ openbox --config-file /home/pi/.config/openbox/lxde-pi-rc.xml
 1253 ?        Sl     0:00          \_ lxpolkit
 1256 ?        Sl    22:56          \_ lxpanel --profile LXDE-pi
```

The whole `lxsession` tree is started by running `x-session-manager` command. If your VNC server runs `lxsession` directly, it could be that your environment is not set correctly: check if you have `$XDG_DATA_DIRS`, `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` and similar variables set inside a VNC session. If not, you may want to edit `~/.vnc/xstartup` to set those variables or use the `x-session-manager` command.

Answer (score 0):

Found this from someone with the same problem.

Might be outdated, but eventually it helps.

> I saved a copy of my ~/.vnc/xstartup
>
> `apt-get install xorg lxde-core tightvncserver`
>
> Started VNC to create config file (xstartup) tightvncserver :1
>
> Then stopped VNC `tightvncserver -kill :1`
>
> Edited config file to start session with LXDE:
>
> `nano ~/.vnc/xstartup`
>
> and added this at the bottom of the file: `lxterminal & /usr/bin/lxsession -s LXDE &
>
> start VNC `tightvncserver :1
>
> and this worked... I now have a menu bar!
>
> the complete ~/.vnc/xstartup as follows:
> `#!/bin/sh
>
> `xrdb $HOME/.Xresources xsetroot -solid grey -cursor_name left_ptr`
> `#x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &`
> `#x-window-manager &`
> `# Fix to make GNOME work export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1 /etc/X11/Xsession lxterminal & /usr/bin/lxsession -s LXDE &`

Link to the source:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=149667

Comment: Unfortunately, with this there are no terninal, bluetooth and wlan items on the panel. 
The correct configuration I get with `/usr/bin/lxsession -s LXDE-pi -e LXDE&`, but I don't get the panel in vnc.